# How to uniquely identity a Person resource in Google People API response from a particular user?

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

`Google People API`, unlike `Google Plus API` doesn't provide an unique `id` for each `Person` resource in the response.

Why has this been deprecated/removed and how to uniquely identify a `Person` in an user's contacts list without an `id`?

Answer (score 7):

In short, use `resourceName` as an ID.

The Google People API is the user's list of *contacts* and have IDs specific to the user. They can create contacts that only have a mailing address or only have a name and no contact info. There is no way for Google to logically collate all of these contacts across all of the Google Contacts users.

Specific contacts or a user have a `resourceName` field that uniquely identifies that resource (contact) for the authenticating user. You basically want to use that as an `id`. This is the value you for use, for example, to query [People.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get).

This is part of an example response of a single contact from People.connections:

```
  {
    "resourceName": "people/103710953423417258027",
    "etag": "qwApd98gduQ=",
    "metadata": {
        "sources": [{
            "type": "CONTACT",
            "id": "1",
            "etag": "#rj+KMFHVyHY="
        }, {
            "type": "PROFILE",
            "id": "103710953423417258027",
            "etag": "#4eZfef/IuMFw="
        }],
        "objectType": "PERSON"
    },
    ...
  }
```

`resourceName` is essentially the "id" of that contact and then in the `metadata` field it lists the sources the contact data comes from. E.g. `CONTACT` is for a Google Contacts entry where the user has manually entered name/phone/email/etc. `PROFILE` is a Google Profile, commonly with Google+ data.

The [Person resource docs](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#resource-person) are a great place to learn more about these values.

Comment: I am talking about the contact `Id`s specific to the user. If you go through the `Google People API`, you won't find any `Id` field being returned in the response. Is this by design or did they forget to include it?

Comment: @jackofblades I've updated the answer with info about `resourceName`

Comment: The Person resource docs mention this: **The resource name may change when adding or removing fields that link a contact and profile such as a verified email, verified phone number, or profile URL.** In that case, we can't use it as an `Id` for syncing and updation, can we?

Comment: `resourceName` and `source.id` are what you have to work with so ya, you kind of have to use them for syncing.

Comment: The personMetadata is supposed to link old and new resourceNames, so you should be able to use it as an ID for syncing as long as you can update IDs.   https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#personmetadata

Comment: You are right. This is not an OOP this is garbage. I am facing the same problem how to identify user who logged in and it is like a nightmare.